# patient profile plot in r

Tags: r, plot

R Script.
I am attempting to create a patient profile plot of the following dummy data.

```
id = c(51308),
  med_name = c("morphine", "codeine", "diamorphine", "codeine", "morphine", "codeine"),
  p_start = c("2010-04-29 12:31:58"),
  p_end = c("2011-05-19T14:05:00Z"),
  mid_point_dates = c("2010-05-09T14:05:00Z", "2010-04-29T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-01T12:52:14Z", "2010-05-13T14:04:00Z", "2010-05-03T14:04:00Z", "2010-04-30T10:34:27Z")
```

id == y axis, date == x axis, with p_start, mid_point_dates and p_end dates == data points.

I have made multiple attempts without success.

Using dummy data, I have done the following, however, I would like to apply to more than one id.

```
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

# Define the data
id = c(51308)
med_name = c("morphine", "codeine", "diamorphine", "codeine", "morphine", "codeine")
p_start = ymd_hms("2010-04-29 12:31:58")
p_end = ymd_hms("2010-05-19T14:05:00Z")
mid_point_dates = ymd_hms(c("2010-05-09T14:05:00Z", "2010-04-29T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-01T12:52:14Z", "2010-05-13T14:04:00Z", "2010-05-03T14:04:00Z", "2010-04-30T10:34:27Z"))

# Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(id, med_name, p_start, p_end, mid_point_dates)

# Define the y-axis categories
id_categories <- unique(df$id)

# Create the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = mid_point_dates, y = id)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = p_end, yend = id, colour = med_name), size = 2, color = "grey") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = med_name, group = med_name, shape = med_name), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "green", "orange")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 15, 16)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = id_categories) +
  labs(title = "Medication Timeline", x = "Date", y = "Patient ID") +
  theme_minimal()
```

and generated the following plot

[image]

Update.
I adjusted the r script to allow for multiple ids and differences in date times, as follows. (overlaps between p_start, p_end and data points lead to the former being brought to the front, which is not intended)

```
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

# Define the data
id = c(214441, 214441, 214441, 214444, 214444, 214446)
med_name = c("morphine", "codeine", "diamorphine", "codeine", "morphine", "drug_X")
p_start = ymd_hms("2010-04-29 12:31:58", "2010-04-29 12:31:58", "2010-04-29 12:31:58", "2010-04-25 12:31:58", "2010-04-25 12:31:58", "2010-04-25 12:31:58")
p_end = ymd_hms("2010-05-19T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-19T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-19 12:31:58", "2010-05-27 12:31:58", "2010-05-27 12:31:58", "2010-05-20 12:31:58")
mid_point_dates = ymd_hms(c("2010-05-09T14:05:00Z", "2010-04-29T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-01T12:52:14Z", "2010-05-13T14:04:00Z", "2010-05-03T14:04:00Z", "2010-04-30T10:34:27Z"))


# Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(id, med_name, p_start, p_end, mid_point_dates)

# Define the y-axis categories
id_categories <- unique(df$id)


ggplot(df, aes(x = mid_point_dates, y = id)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = p_start, xend = p_end, yend = id, colour = med_name), size = 2, color = "grey") +
geom_point(aes(x = mid_point_dates, y = id, colour = med_name, group = med_name), size = 3) +
geom_point(aes(x = p_start, y = id, fill = "white"), size = 3, shape = 23, color = "black") +
geom_point(aes(x = p_end, y = id), size = 3, shape = 23, color = "black") +
scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "green", "orange", "blue"), name = "medication") +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 15, 16, 2), name = "Start/End") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("white"), name = "p_start/p_end") +
scale_y_discrete(limits = id_categories) +
labs(title = "Medication Timeline", x = "Date", y = "Patient ID") +
theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to be some in your data generating code - could you edit to ensure reproducibility? Also what is a patient profile plot? Can you give an example?

Comment: The following url (https://cyntegrity.com/patient-profiles-better-understand-your-patients/) gives examples of patient profile plots

Comment: This another url (https://www.khstats.com/blog/trt-timelines/multiple-vars) with patient profile plot examples

Comment: Thank you! These are all different (visits, AEs, etc). Which one would you want? Also, could you please edit/update your question with these links (or better, embed images of specific plots that you want) and also correct your example data?

Answer (score 1):

Making up a data object for multiple patients (a list, which is combined into a tibble) you could do it like this:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    patients <- list(
      "patient A" = 
        tibble(
          id = c(51308),
          med_name = c("morphine", "codeine", "diamorphine", "codeine", "morphine", "codeine"),
          p_start = c("2010-04-29 12:31:58"),
          p_end = c("2011-05-19T14:05:00Z"),
          mid_point_dates = c("2010-05-09T14:05:00Z", "2010-04-29T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-01T12:52:14Z", "2010-05-13T14:04:00Z", "2010-05-03T14:04:00Z", "2010-04-30T10:34:27Z")
      ),
      "Patient B" = 
        tibble(
          id = c(51309),
          med_name = c("morphine", "codeine", "diamorphine", "codeine", "morphine", "codeine"),
          p_start = c("2010-04-29 12:31:58"),
          p_end = c("2011-05-19T14:05:00Z"),
          mid_point_dates = c("2010-05-09T14:05:00Z", "2010-04-29T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-01T12:52:14Z", "2010-05-13T14:04:00Z", "2010-05-03T14:04:00Z", "2010-04-30T10:34:27Z")
        ),
      "Patient C" = 
        tibble(
          id = c(51310),
          med_name = c("morphine", "codeine", "diamorphine", "codeine", "morphine", "codeine"),
          p_start = c("2010-04-29 12:31:58"),
          p_end = c("2011-05-19T14:05:00Z"),
          mid_point_dates = c("2010-05-09T14:05:00Z", "2010-04-29T14:05:00Z", "2010-05-01T12:52:14Z", "2010-05-13T14:04:00Z", "2010-05-03T14:04:00Z", "2010-04-30T10:34:27Z")
        )
    )
    data <- bind_rows(patients, .id = "Patient_id") %>%
      group_by(Patient_id) %>%
      mutate(y = cur_group_id()) 
    
    y_axis_labels <- as.character(unique(data$id))
    y_axis_breaks <- seq(1, length(y_axis_labels), by = 1)
    
    # Create the plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = mid_point_dates, y = y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = p_end, y = y, yend = y, colour = med_name), size = 2, color = "grey") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = med_name, group = med_name, shape = med_name), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "green", "orange")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 15, 16)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_axis_breaks, labels = y_axis_labels) +
  labs(title = "Medication Timeline", x = "Date", y = "Patient ID") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

Which gives you a plot like this (it's rough & dirty but you get the idea):
[image]